# Sort custom dictionary with swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, dictionary

I want to group my data by date, so I create a custom dictionary `[String: [myData]]` to keep track of my data. (The key stores the value of date in String.) Also, I found that the dictionary I got is **unsorted**.

I used `.sorted(by:)` to sort my dictionary, however, it returns another data structure `[(key: String, value: [myData])]` instead of what I expected `[String: [myData]]`, any idea?

```
struct myData {
var name: String
var date: Date

init(name: String, date: Date) {
    self.name = name
    self.date = date
    }
}

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"

let x1 = myData(name: "a", date: dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-10-15")!)
let x2 = myData(name: "b", date: dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-10-15")!)
let x3 = myData(name: "z", date: dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-10-12")!)
let x4 = myData(name: "d", date: dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-10-31")!)
let x5 = myData(name: "c", date: dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-10-07")!)
let x6 = myData(name: "f", date: dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-10-06")!)

var myArr = [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6]

var myArrayByDate = [String: [myData]]()

for item in myArr {
    let date = dateFormatter.string(from: item.date)
    myArrayByDate[date] == nil ? myArrayByDate[date] = [item] : myArrayByDate[date]?.append(item)
}

print(myArrayByDate) // unsorted

// Sorting
// sortedArray: [(key: String, value: [myData])]

let sortedArray = myArrayByDate.sorted { (s1, s2) -> Bool in
if let d1 = dateFormatter.date(from: s1.key), 
   let d2 = dateFormatter.date(from: s2.key) {
        if d1.compare(d2) == .orderedDescending {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered collections. If you'd like a collection with order, perhaps you should use another type of collection, e.g. an array of tuples (where `tupleElement.0` would correspond to "key", and `tupleElement.1` "value", where the latter could be used to sort the array).

Comment: Oh i see. I'll try this way. ty

Comment: The question says dictionary but you are trying to sort an Array.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

```
struct myData {
var name: String
var date: Date

init(name: String, date: Date) {
    self.name = name
    self.date = date
    }
}

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"

        let x1 = myData(name: "a", date: dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-10-15")!)
        let x2 = myData(name: "b", date: dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-10-15")!)
        let x3 = myData(name: "z", date: dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-10-12")!)
        let x4 = myData(name: "d", date: dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-10-31")!)
        let x5 = myData(name: "c", date: dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-10-07")!)
        let x6 = myData(name: "f", date: dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-10-06")!)

        let myArr = [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6]

        var myArrayByDate:[String: [myData]] = [:]

        for item in myArr
        {
            let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: item.date)
            if let arr = myArrayByDate[dateStr]
            {
                var arrayItems = arr 
                arrayItems.append(item)
                arrayItems.sort(by: { (s1, s2) -> Bool in
                    if s1.date.compare(s1.date) == .orderedDescending {
                        return true
                    }
                    return false
                })
                myArrayByDate[dateStr] = arrayItems
            }
            else
            {
                myArrayByDate[dateStr] = [item]
            }
        }
```

I think it will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the **keys** of the `myArrayByDate` dictionary as sorted so that when you try access your `myArrayByDate` dictionary in a sorted way, you could use the **keys sorted** previously.

```
let sortedKeys = myArrayByDate.keys.sorted { s1, s2 in
  guard let d1 = dateFormatter.date(from: s1) else {
    return false
  }

  guard let d2 = dateFormatter.date(from: s2) else {
    return false
  }

  return d1.compare(d2) == .orderedDescending
}

// print dictionary sorted
for key in sortedKeys {
  print(myArrayByDate[key])
}
```